# The equivalence of matrix induced norm definition

Tags: normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I have seen three different version of matrix induced norm definition from several numerical linear algebra books:
$$\|A\|_{a,b} =\max\limits_{x} \{ \|Ax\|_{b}: \|x\|_{a} \leq 1  \}\quad (1)$$
$$\|A\|_{a,b} =\max\limits_{x} \{ \|Ax\|_{b}: \|x\|_{a} = 1  \}\quad (2)$$
$$\|A\|_{a,b} = \max\limits_{x} \{ \frac{\|Ax\|_{b}}{\|x\|_{a}}: x \neq 0 \}\quad (3)$$.

For (2) being equivalent to (3) is obvious, since it is just divided by 1, but I cannot see how the (1) be equivalent to (2) and (3). Can anyone explain this a little bit to me?

Comment: I don't think (3) is usually this -- instead, isn't it $x\neq 0$?

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah, you are right, that is my typo, I have changed that, thanks.

Comment: @ClementC. But this actually make me more confused, since we are not restrict the $\|x\|$， then, if we let the  $\| x\| <1$, then $\max\limits_{x \neq 0} \left\{ \| Ax\|_b/\| x\|_a\right\} $ how could I determine the max?

Comment: You can't have a strict inequality in the definition with a max -- you need to have a sup there, as the maximum may not be achieved.

Comment: Hopefully, my answer makes it clearer why (1) and (2) are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, those are stated  with $\sup$ instead of $\max$, but the question is basically the same.

Note first that
$$
\max\{ \|Ax\|_{b}: \|x\|_{a} \leq 1  \} \geq \max\{ \|Ax\|_{b}: \|x\|_{a} = 1  \}
$$
so to prove the two are actually equal, it suffices to show the other inequality.

Take any $x$ with  $\|x\|_a\leq 1$. If $x=0$, then $\|Ax\|_b=0$ and any unit vector $y$ satisfies $\|Ay\|_b\geq \|Ax\|_b$. Otherwise, consider $y := \frac{x}{\|x\|_a}$, which by definition has $\|y\|_a = 1$, and note that
$$
\|Ay\|_b = \frac{\|Ax\|_b}{\|x\|_a} \geq \|Ax\|_b
$$
where the inequality is because $\|x\|_a\leq 1$. So, for every $x$ with $\|x\|_a\leq 1$, there exists a $y$ with norm $\|y\|_a= 1$ such that $\|Ax\|_{b}\leq \|Ay\|_{b}$, which implies
$$
\max\{ \|Ax\|_{b}: \|x\|_{a} \leq 1  \} \leq \max\{ \|Ax\|_{b}: \|x\|_{a} = 1  \}
$$
and we are done.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it several times to try and give the clearest version of the argument.

Comment: It is really clear ! thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @BlackSith You're welcome! Glad it helped.